# How to include a srv from another pkg in ROS2 - fatal error: No such file or directory

Tags: ros, ros2, include

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have followed the basic srv example for ROS2 from the official website. However, i tried to create myself the service instead of using example_interfaces (intern from ROS2). I first tried to create the service inside my pkg code (as in ROS1) but i couldnt include it correctly. So i tried to create the service in an extern package (i know its the best practice in ROS2) but i got the same problem when including. My srv file is Suma.srv, inside dev_ws/src/custom_pkg/srv. I will appreciate the solution either for include my inside srv file either for the external srv pkg.
My srv pkg can compile correctly but the one with the code cant. Here i share my custom_pkg with the srv:

```
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(custom_interfaces)

# Default to C99
if(NOT CMAKE_C_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
endif()

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)
# uncomment the following section in order to fill in
# further dependencies manually.
# find_package(<dependency> REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "srv/Suma.srv"
)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # uncomment the line when a copyright and license is not present in all source files
  #set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # uncomment the line when this package is not in a git repo
  #set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_export_dependencies(rosidl_default_runtime)

ament_package()
```

Now i show the package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>custom_interfaces</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="pedro@todo.todo">pedro</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>
  <buildtool_depend>rosidl_default_generators</buildtool_depend>

  <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>

  <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

Then, i will show my cpp_srvcli package (it works with the predetermined pkg example_interfaces):
CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(cpp_srvcli)

# Default to C99
if(NOT CMAKE_C_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
endif()

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(custom_interfaces REQUIRED)
find_package(example_interfaces REQUIRED)
# find_package(rosidl_cmake REQUIRED)
# find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

# rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
#   "srv/Suma.srv"
# )

# include_directories(include)

#ament_export_dependencies(rosidl_default_runtime)
#include_directories(include ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(server 
  src/add_two_ints_server.cpp
  #src/main_server.cpp
  )

add_executable(client
  src/add_two_ints_client.cpp
  # src/main_client.cpp
  )

# rosidl_target_interfaces(server
#   ${PROJECT_NAME} "rosidl_typesupport_cpp")
# rosidl_target_interfaces(client
#   ${PROJECT_NAME} "rosidl_typesupport_cpp")

ament_target_dependencies(server custom_interfaces example_interfaces rclcpp)
ament_target_dependencies(client custom_interfaces example_interfaces rclcpp)

install(TARGETS
  server
  client
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # uncomment the line when a copyright and license is not present in all source files
  #set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # uncomment the line when this package is not in a git repo
  #set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()
```

package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>cpp_srvcli</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="pedro@todo.todo">pedro</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>
  <!-- <buildtool_depend>rosidl_default_generators</buildtool_depend>
  <buildtool_depend>rosidl_cmake</buildtool_depend> -->

  <!-- <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend> -->

  <depend>rclcpp</depend>
  <depend>custom_interfaces</depend>

  <!-- <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group> -->

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

And finally my add_two_ints_client (i know this wont help too much):

```
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "example_interfaces/srv/add_two_ints.hpp"
#include "custom_interfaces/srv/Suma.hpp"

#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

  if (argc != 3) {
      RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("rclcpp"), "usage: add_two_ints_client X Y");
      return 1;
  }

  std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("add_two_ints_client");
  rclcpp::Client<custom_interfaces::srv::Suma>::SharedPtr client =
    node->create_client<custom_interfaces::srv::Suma>("add_two_ints"); //example_interfaces::srv::AddTwoInts

  auto request = std::make_shared<custom_interfaces::srv::Suma::Request>();
  request->a = atoll(argv[1]);
  request->b = atoll(argv[2]);

  while (!client->wait_for_service(std::chrono::seconds(1s))) {
    if (!rclcpp::ok()) {
      RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger("rclcpp"), "Interrupted while waiting for the service. Exiting.");
      return 0;
    }
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("rclcpp"), "service not available, waiting again...");
  }

  auto result = client->async_send_request(request);
  // Wait for the result.
  if (rclcpp::spin_until_future_complete(node, result) == rclcpp::FutureReturnCode::SUCCESS)
  {
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("rclcpp"), "Sum: %ld", result.get()->sum);
  } else {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger("rclcpp"), "Failed to call service add_two_ints");
  }

  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399665/how-to-include-a-srv-from-another-pkg-in-ros2---fatal-error:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [Peanpepu](https://answers.ros.org/users/102601/peanpepu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2022-04-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Peanpepu](https://answers.ros.org/users/102601/peanpepu/) on 2022-04-26**:
I have already found the problem. Although the srv name file must start with a capital letter, when you use the include inside the file.cpp you have to include starting with lowercase letter: `#include "cpp_srvcli/srv/suma.hpp"`

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-04-26**:
Can you check each step [with this tutorial?](https://roboticsbackend.com/ros2-create-custom-message/#Createbuilduse_your_own_ROS2_custom_service_Srv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not `Suma.hpp`, it's `suma.hpp`.

You can also see this for yourself if you go to `~/dev_ws/install/custom_interfaces/include/custom_interfaces/srv` You will see the files `suma.hpp` there.

EDIT interestingly enough, naming the actual files should be CamelCased (it doesn't accept underscores) while the resulting hpp is under_scored

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2022-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2